# New column with other dimension

Tags: r

```
Des          Price                  New column             New column 2 

a   27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82   27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82  price decreased and increased
b   19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87   19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87  price decreased and increased
c   32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31 price decre, incre and decre 
d   32.25                           32.25                   Constant
```

Can we add a new dimension to the data. For example, In new column we have 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82, so can we add another column and tell, the price decreased and increased. I mean the initial value was 27.82, then it got decreased and then increased. Similarly for 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31, here it is decreased, increased, decreased.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you need. Can you add you desired output in the question?

Comment: i have edited my questtion

Answer (score 0):

**Original question**

```
df = data.frame(Des = c("a","c"),
                    NewColumn = c("27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82", "32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(v = NewColumn) %>%                                   # duplicate the column
  separate_rows(v, convert = T) %>%                           # separate that column to rows
  group_by(Des) %>%                                           # for each Des value
  mutate(flag = ifelse(v < lag(v), "Dec", "Inc")) %>%         # flag if the value was decreased on increased
  na.omit() %>%                                               # remove rows with NAs
  group_by(Des, NewColumn) %>%                                # for each Des and NewColumn combination
  summarise(NewColumn2 = paste0(flag, collapse = ", ")) %>%   # create a string sequence of flags
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Des   NewColumn               NewColumn2   
#   <fct> <fct>                   <chr>        
# 1 a     27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82   Dec, Inc     
# 2 c     32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31 Dec, Inc, Dec
```

Note that based on the example you provided I assumed that

a) Column `Price` is not needed for your calculations

b) There are no cases where 2 consecutive values in `NewColumn` are the same (i.e. you'll always have an "increase" or a "decrease")

**Edit**

In case you have a single value you can use this:

```
df = data.frame(Des = c("a","b","c"),
                NewColumn = c("27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82", "12", "32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(v = NewColumn) %>%                                  
  separate_rows(v, convert = T) %>%                         
  group_by(Des) %>%                                         
  mutate(flag = ifelse(v < lag(v), "Dec", "Inc"),
         NumValues = n(),
         flag = ifelse(NumValues == 1, "Const", flag)) %>%        
  na.omit() %>%                                              
  group_by(Des, NewColumn) %>%                                
  summarise(NewColumn2 = paste0(flag, collapse = ", ")) %>%   
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Des   NewColumn               NewColumn2   
#   <fct> <fct>                   <chr>        
# 1 a     27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82   Dec, Inc     
# 2 b     12                      Const        
# 3 c     32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31 Dec, Inc, Dec
```

Comment: ok even if it is 2/5/7/2/4/1, will it show inc, inc, dec, inc, dec (i am starting with 2 here. So 5 is inc, then 7 is inc from 5, then 2 is dec from 5 and so on, This is logic

Comment: That's fine. Still not two same values in a row (i.e. consecutive values). My approach should work for you.

Comment: OK cool. I got  it. But if there is only 1 value in a cell like 12. I need as Constant(Con).Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you provide another example that has a case like this and show how you want your output to be?

Comment: I just saw for 8.25 / 10.2 it is showing as Dec. Why?

Comment: 47.28 / 5.35 it is showing as inc . May be for many. I checked randomly

Comment: If i do it seperately for 8.25 / 10.2  and 47.28 / 5.35, It is showing correctly, but in the my list there are many, When i execute it the result is not proper

Comment: There is some issue i guess. I check for few more. It is showing wrong

Comment: If you the process works on the example data but not on your big data frame you have to find out what are the differences. Can you post an example where my process doesn't work?

Comment: No . Can we not make it big data frame ??? It's happening correctly but randomly it's not taking??? What's the reason

Comment: @ antoniosk why it's not happening for big data frame??

Comment: No idea. You have to post your big data frame using `dput` so I can investigate.

Comment: U didn't face this kind of issue anytime??

Comment: No, but I used only the small dataset of my example. Every time I run my example I get the same result.

Comment: Hi Antoniosk, I tried. But still same problem. You know the reason. By any chance is it other way round. For 8.25 / 10.2, is it reading from right and hence coming as Dec

Answer (score 0):

With Base R:

```
df$NewColumn1 <- sapply(df$NewColumn, function(x){
  temp <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(x), split = "/")[[1]])
  if(length(temp) > 1){
    return(paste(ifelse(temp[-1] < head(temp, -1), "Dec", 
                 ifelse(temp[-1] > head(temp, -1), "Inc", "Const")), 
          collapse = ", "))
  }else{
    return("Const")
  }
})
```

**Output:**

```
  Des               NewColumn      NewColumn1
1   a   27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82        Dec, Inc
2   b                      12           Const
3   c 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31   Dec, Inc, Dec
4   d       16 / 13 / 13 / 15 Dec, Const, Inc
```

**Data** (Modification to @AntoniosK's data):

```
df <- structure(list(Des = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), NewColumn = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("12", "16 / 13 / 13 / 15", "27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82", 
"32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Des", 
"NewColumn"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```